# Any idea of scope which can control activities(screen) and hold values?

Tags: android

This question is most for a discussion.
In many case, we want to finish activities not only one.
Always, we want to send values to other activity.

In traditional ways.We use eventBus and sometimes startActivityForResult.I don't think either of them is a perfect idea.

And now, we have viewModel, which have a store let fragment load the main viewModel.And in some other client(like reactive which I'm not good at),they have a store to transfer data.

So I prefer if there is a better idea to make do this event easier.

Actually I didn't do much work in this.But some code maybe useful for this.

```
interface IScope {
    fun registerScreens(screen: IScreen)

    fun unRegisterScreens(screen: IScreen)

    fun finishAll()
}
```

```
interface IScreen {

    fun getScope(): IScope

    fun finish()


}
```

```
class ScopeSample: IScope {

     val scopeData: LiveData<Any>


}
```

```
class Activity1: IScreen {

    override fun getScope(): IScope {
       return Scope.create("scopeKey")
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
       getScope().registerScreen(this)
       getScope<ScopeSample>().scopeData.observe(customLifeCycleOwner,{})
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
       getScope().unRegisterScreen(this)
    }

    override fun finish() { finish() }
}
```

```
class Activity2: IScreen {

    override fun getScope(): IScope {
       return Scope.create("scopeKey")
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
       button2.setOnClickListener() { getScope().scopeLiveData.updateValue()
       button.setOnClickListener() { getScope().finishAll() }
    }

    override fun finish() { finish() }
}
```

The code is just my thinking.It must have lots of problem.
Even though for this thinking, I want to know any library have done this or anyone have nice ideas of this thinking.